# Cant Load The CSS File In The Same Folder When I Deploy

Tags: java, html, css, servlets

I have css files and HTML file put in the samefolder folder like this: [The css file is in the asset folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThIOF.png)

But when i deploy the project the web, just load the html file, the css doesn't. In HTML file, i add the tag `<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/libs/css/style.css">` like this but it doesn't work. 
Help me. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: can you try `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/libs/css/style.css">`

Comment: i have try but it doesn't work :((

Comment: Open the HTML file inside a Browser. Then toggle the Browser's developer tools and check the error in the console. It should clearly state if the resource was loaded or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been solved my problem. I need to name all files css, font and other things into the Filter to load it. Sorry everyone because i forgot to tell every one about i have the Filter file :<. Thanks for support me.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a really basic reply and apologies if so, but have you spelt the file name the same in both places? For example, could your link in your .html be for style.css but the names of the file is actually style**s**.css? I've done this plenty of times!